# Validate XML with Schema and get validation errors in XML

Tags: xslt, xsd

This is a general question, I do not have any XSLT for this yet.

Is it possible to develop an XSLT which will let Schema to validate the input file (XML) and if there are any validation errors in XML then we can get those in XML file as output?

My requirement is: First I want to validate the input XML, if XML has any errors then I want to catch those and then want to show them in proper format (more descriptive, by generating a validation report).

Please suggest if there is any way only in XSLT.

Comment: A while back I considered writing an XSLT that converted an XSD into an XSLT that output validation errors. The biggest blocker was XSLT 1.0's inability to do regex. XSLT is turing complete, so it's theoretically possible, but I wouldn't even consider it without at least XSLT 2.0. However, XSLT can't process malformed XML, so you're going to have to have an 'is it even valid XML?' step first, and handle errors from that separately.

Comment: It feels like a useless way of faking XSD (xmllint can do the validation and show issues in a pretty readable way). Plus you'll loose every existing XSD integration (ie: Netbeans can read a XSD, give proper autocompletion while writing the file, and validate it with clickable links to erroneous lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard/interoperable XSLT solution to this, but Saxon-EE offers the saxon:validate() extension function which does pretty-much exactly what you are asking for (except that the result is in the form of XSLT 3.0 maps rather than XML).

Details here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/validate

Recent releases of Saxon-EE also have an `InvalidityHandler` callback interface which you can implement to capture details of validation errors, and there's an implementation of this called `InvalidityReportGenerator` which produces an XML report of validation errors. You could easily write an XSLT to transform this report into a different format.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this. Is there any working example if these functions? InvalidityReportGenerator, and InvalidityHandler? I am new in Saxon-EE, so just want to see how to use them and how they work. I am also trying to google them.

Comment: I'm not sure we have much in the way of examples, but the Javadoc is referenced from http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.lib/InvalidityHandler ; there's a general discussion at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing/validation-api/schema-s9api, and the format of the reports file is described in validation-reports.xsd which is in the saxon-resources download file.

Answer (score 0):

A schema-aware XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) processor can use `xsl:import-schema` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#import-schema) to import a W3C XSD schema and then you can write match patterns of the form `match="document-node(schema-element(someRootElementName))"` to match only on valid input documents and if you write a second template matching not validated document nodes with e.g. `match="document-node()"` then you could identify if your input is not valid and output an error message, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemaxslt/#validin.

However, I don't think XSLT used that way is a good way to create a detailed report with validation errors as I don't see how to identify validation problems that way, you would better check the API of your validating XML parser on how to access the reported error messages.

Comment: Thanks, this particular example worked for me. Now I have the setup of Saxon-EE. I had few more questions which I just posted to Michael Kay .

Answer (score 0):

You can try an ISO Schematron validator that generates a report in XML-based SVRL format: http://www.schematron.com/validators.html.

If you don't have an XML Schema file yet then I'd recommend to create a Schematron validation file (*.sch) to describe the target format rather than XML Schema file. If you're required to use an existing XML Schema file then you can transform it with "XSD to Schematron converter": http://www.schematron.com/resources.html